# How do i store JSON from a link to java script array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

Hi iam trying to store this JSON to my javascript array.Is there any way to that.am using following code and its not working at all.

my json [JSON](http://zonewebs.org/website/naveen/source/location.php)

```
 [{"id":"1","Intensity":"1","Location":"12.48,77.26"},{"id":"2","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.47,77.26"},{"id":"3","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.47,77.27"},{"id":"4","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.46,77.24"},{"id":"5","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.44,77.24"},{"id":"6","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.44,77.28"},{"id":"7","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.50,77.28"},{"id":"8","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.45,77.30"},{"id":"9","Intensity":"2","Location":"12.41,77.21"}]
```

my html code with JS for getting json data

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="response">werer</div>
    <script>
$.get('http://zonewebs.org/website/naveen/source/location.php', function(data) {
  $('#response').append(data);

});
</script>
</dody>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse to convert **valid** json to javascript array

```
var dataArray = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: u will get your json data into a javascript array using the above code.Then u can handle it as you like

Comment: As i see your json response there is no property in the json response. Instead of data.property use data

Comment: but its not working am getting blank page instead of jason data

Comment: You are using data.property. use data

Comment: $('#response').append(data );??

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid.[Try jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/). Remove this from the end :

```
{"var":"stuff"}
```

Then use :

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: how can i remove that part??